# LiveCharts Cartesian Mapping and Configuration with custom Labels

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I have plotted the Cartesian chart using X and Y values, to mimic step chart (x values are not consistent). Is it possible to add custom x Labels for each step changed in Y value? Or similar labels like in a bar chart.

```
 var values = new ChartValues<Point>();

Loop:
    var point = new Point() { X = entry.DailyXFrom, Y = entry.YValue };

    values.Add(point);
    point = new Point() { X = entry.DailyXTo, Y = entry.YValue };
    values.Add(point);
    tempLabels.Add(entry.DailyVolume.ToString());


            seriesCollectionDaily = new SeriesCollection
                      {
                        new LineSeries
                        {
                          Configuration = new CartesianMapper<Point>()
                            .X(point => point.X) 
                            .Y(point => point.Y)
                            ,
                          Fill = Brushes.Transparent,
                          Title = "Series",
                          Values = values,
                          PointGeometry = null,
                          LineSmoothness = 0

                        }
                    };
 XAxis.Separator.IsEnabled = true;
 XAxis.Labels = tempLabels.ToArray();
chart.DataContext = this;


 <lvc:CartesianChart Name="chart"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Series="{Binding seriesCollectionDaily }" >
                    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX >
                        <lvc:Axis Name="XAxis" Title=""   LabelsRotation="0" Foreground="Black" >
                            <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                                <lvc:Separator Name="LabelSeparator"></lvc:Separator>
                            </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                        </lvc:Axis>
                    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
 </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

What I got:
[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve. Is it possible?
[image]

Comment: You should use `StepLineSeries` to create a step chart (instead of `LineSeries`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add sections to your chart axis.

To draw vertical sections you have to define a `SectionsCollection` of `AxisSection` items and bind it to `Axis.Sections` of the x-axis.
By setting `AxisSection.Value` you can define the position on the axis. Use `AxisSection.SectionWidth` to define the width of the section. The default is `1`, which draws a simple stroke when `AxisSection.StrokeThickness` is set.

The following example uses `StepLineSeries` to plot a step chart.
To give an example, it shows two vertical lines placed at the corresponding x-value: a simple line (`SectionWidth = 1`) and a section where `SectionWidth > 1` (e.g., to highlight a range):

[image]

**Data Model**

```
public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public DataModel()
  {
    this.SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
    {
      new StepLineSeries()
      {
        Configuration = new CartesianMapper<ObservablePoint>()
          .X(point => point.X)
          .Y(point => point.Y)
          .Stroke(point => point.Y > 0.3 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.LightGreen),
        Values = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>
        {
          new ObservablePoint(0, 5),
          new ObservablePoint(20, 0),
          new ObservablePoint(30, 5),
          new ObservablePoint(40, 0),
          new ObservablePoint(80, 5),
        }
      }
    };

    // Add two sections at x=20 and x=30
    this.SectionsCollection = new SectionsCollection()
    {
      new AxisSection()
      {
        Value = 20,
        Stroke = Brushes.Red,
        StrokeThickness = 1
      },
      new AxisSection()
      {
        Value = 30,
        SectionWidth = 50,
        Stroke = Brushes.Red,
        StrokeThickness = 1
      }
    };
  }

  public Func<double, string> LabelFormatter => value => $"{value}ms";
  public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
  public SectionsCollection SectionsCollection { get; set; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Chart View**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <DataModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <CartesianChart Height="500"
                  Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
    <CartesianChart.AxisX>
      <Axis Sections="{Binding SectionsCollection}"
            LabelFormatter="{Binding LabelFormatter}">
        <Axis.Separator>
          <Separator Step="10" />
        </Axis.Separator>
      </Axis>
    </CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <CartesianChart.AxisY>
      <Axis>
        <Axis.Separator>
          <Separator Step="5" />
        </Axis.Separator>
      </Axis>
    </CartesianChart.AxisY>
  </CartesianChart>
</Window>
```